# Web scrapping with Beautifulsoup returns no text eventhough it is in the html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scrapping and using Beautifulsoup. I need help as I don't understand why my code is returning no text when there is text in the inspect view on the website.

Here is my simple code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.nummerplade.net/nummerplade/Dd97487.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,"html.parser")

name = soup.find("span",id="debitorer_name1")

print(name)
```

The output of running my code is:

```
<span id="debitorer_name1"></span>
```

When I inspect the HTML on the website I can see the desired name I want to extract, but not when running my script. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you reload site the data is reflecting in right side pane it takes same time so where it is uses dynamic data loading and it will not be visible in `soup`

How to find URL which renders dynamic data:

1. Go to Network tab and reload site and in left side just type the data that you want to search it will give you URL
2. Now go to Headers and copy `user-agent`, `referer`  for `headers` and it will return data as in `json` format and you can extract what so data you want

> ```
> import requests
> headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", "referer": "https://www.nummerplade.net/"}
> res=requests.get("https://data3.nummerplade.net/bilbogen2.php?stelnr=salza2bt3nh162519",headers=headers)
> ```

Output:

```
'Sebastian Carl Schwabe'
```

Image:
[image]